# What are the pros and cons of having both snap and flatpak on enabled on Ubuntu? Would you recommend it?

Tags: snap, flatpak

What are the pros and cons of having both snap and flatpak on enabled on ubuntu? Would you recommend it? I'm currently running ubuntu version 22.10 and plan to upgrade to 23.04 in a few weeks.

Comment: This question can’t really be answered as every “solution” will be opinion based. That said, the only con (that I’m aware of) is that you’ll be using Ubuntu in a manner that Canonical would prefer you didn’t 

Comment: Discussion and opinion based questions can be asked on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/). They are [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: If you are RAM limited at all, I would purge snap. If youre using PCs with 4GB ram or less, get rid of snap

Answer (score 2):

Pro: You have additional choices.

Con: You must learn the proper tools to avoid becoming confused. The additional complexity is YOUR responsibility to manage and maintain.

There are a lot of claims out there that A is superior to B. And counter-claims that B is superior to A. Ignore all such noise.

Use what you want to use. Use what you understand. Use what you can properly manage and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Flatpak apps often give me the slushy, inhibited sensation that I am struggling to walk through deep snow without snowshoes on. In a word the performance is slow. Snaps on my machine are snappy. I often don't notice any performance difference between snap packages and native .deb packages. As a result I sometimes install both .deb and snap packages of the same app to test new features without incurring a performance hit.

Compared to Flathub I think the Snap Store has a pretty good selection of software.